# Is it possible to bind ^/ and M-/ in nano

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, nano

I've been configuring nano with the hopes of giving it the same keybindings as emacs, so that I can use nano for quick edits and emacs when I'm working on actual projects. However, I've run into a small problem: nano does not seem to want to let me reassign the `^/` key combination (to undo). Does anyone know how/if this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most terminals (a side-effect of the way ASCII is encoded), `^/` is the same as `^_` (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>).  The help-screen for nano on my Debian 7 machine shows that as *Go to line and column number*.

*M-/* is harder, since there is no standard for this.  However, nano uses the assumption that the <kbd>meta</kbd> keys simply have an <kbd>escape</kbd> character as prefix.  Again, the help-screen shows a binding (which, lacking a standard) cites this as *Go to the last line of the file*.  Your terminal may not send the key that nano expects.

In the [nanorc](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nanorc.5.html) manual page, the binding of control for non-alphas is not mentioned.  A quick check shows that it does recognize `^_` but not `^/`.  Also (setting `xterm` to *Meta sends escape*), the `M-/` binding is recognized.  Here's the example I tried:

```
bind ^/ help all
bind ^_ exit all
bind M-/ help all
```

The binding for `^/` is ignored whether or not I comment-out the `^_` binding.  On my keyboard, the two send the same character.  Very likely you have the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks. That got ^/ working. It turns out that M-/ works directly in my terminal (konsole).